# SQL Server - Is it possible to have multiple values between column1 and column2?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to ask about SQL Server `BETWEEN` operator.

Normally, it can be used like this.

```
WHERE 'value' BETWEEN column_name1 AND column_name2
```

or

```
WHERE column_name BETWEEN 'value1' AND 'value2'
```

but in my case, I have multiple values, and want to put it on value zone

```
WHERE 'value1, value2, value3' BETWEEN  column_name1 AND column_name2
```

Is this possible?

Comment: You never told us whether you want to OR or AND the three between conditions, but in any case I think you have to list the conditions separately.

Comment: Do you mean 'value1, value2, value3' or 'value1', 'value2', 'value3'

Comment: don't make your life difficult. Simply use 3 separate BETWEEN statement

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like below if that can work for you. Put these values in a temporary table variable.

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(
 DateVal DATETIME
)

INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES ('2017-05-06')
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES ('2017-06-23')

SELECT * FROM Table a JOIN @tbl b 
ON 1=1
WHERE b.DateVal BETWEEN CreationDate AND ModificationDate
```

Otherwise, you can always compare it value by value.